# Add Dynamic content to Sphinx

Tags: javascript, html, jinja2, python-sphinx, templating

I would like to add a star rating widget to a Sphinx documentation website. As far as I know, Sphinx is a "static" site generator. I've added some javascript that enables me to click and select a star rating, but without PHP and MySQL to submit and store the ratings, I don't see how I could implement such a feature in Sphinx.

Did somebody already try to add such a capability to a Sphinx documentation website? I'm aware of the existence of "[Staticman](https://github.com/eduardoboucas/staticman)", which allows users to add dynamic interaction to static websites, but I'm looking for further alternatives.

Comment: Please try to narrow this down to one specific problem. Did you try "staticman"? If you want software recommendations, go to https://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/.

Comment: @mzjn: Thank you for the hint about software recommendations! 
I haven't tried "staticman" yet. I'm trying to implement a star rating system in Sphinx, which basically serves static content to the users. So I have to figure out a way to store users' ratings somewhere and display the rating statistics to visitors.